# I can't load my chrome profile by selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver`
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\avayn\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'E:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
#options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver.get("https://www.ea.com/tr-tr/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/")
time.sleep(15)
transfer = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/section/nav/button[3]").click
```

Normally, I can login automatically, but my chrome profile is not loading.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I am not getting an error message but my chrome profile is not loaded as passwords, cookies